# JavaFX: Gradually changing DoubleProperty that is being bounded to in background thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, crash, thread-safety

I'm trying to programmatically animate the resizing of a group of rectangles in JavaFX, but I'm having issues most probably due to threading.

The program crashes when it comes to `widthOfRectangles.set(...` even though it's a loop in the background thread and that it is supposed to stop. I'm assuming that setting the DoubleProperty where all my rectangle widths are bound to in `Platform.runLater` won't really work.

So I tried it again without `Platform.runLater` (not the code shown below), but this time, it lags for the duration of which the rectangles are supposed to expand/minimize, then suddenly jumps to the end state - at least it didn't crash, but it is not the smooth animation that I was looking for.

Is it possible to smoothly interpolate attributes of Nodes via PropertyBindings at all, and if so, how would I go about doing it without freezing the JavaFX main thread?

```
expandProgressGraphic = new Thread(new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception { 
    while (widthOfRectangles.get() < 130) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> 
        widthOfRectangles.set(widthOfRectangles.get() + (130 - widthOfRectangles.get()) / 3 + 2));

        try {
        Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    widthOfRectangles.set(130);
    return null;
    }
});
expandProgressGraphic.setDaemon(true);

minimizeProgressGraphic = new Thread(new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        while (widthOfRectangles.get() > 40) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> 
                widthOfRectangles.set(widthOfRectangles.get() - (widthOfRectangles.get() - 40) / 3 - 2));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        widthOfRectangles.set(40);
        return null;
    }
});
expandProgressGraphic.setDaemon(true);


pane.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if(widthOfRectangles.get() != 130 && event.getX() < widthOfRectangles.get() && !expandProgressGraphic.isAlive()) {
            expandProgressGraphic.run();
        } else if(widthOfRectangles.get() != 40 && event.getX() > widthOfRectangles.get() && !minimizeProgressGraphic.isAlive()){
            minimizeProgressGraphic.run();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should call the thread's `start` method, not `run`. `run` calls the inner `Runnable` on the same thread.  

Also, consider using [`Transition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html)

Answer (score 0):

Once again, thanks to @sillyfly.

I should have used `Thread.start()` instead of `Thread.run()`